# Redux/React: Dropdown options each generate different number of fields, do I need an action/reducer for each one of those selections?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a dropdown that dynamically generates a certain number of fields depending on user selection (1, 5, 13, etc) and I'm building it inside an application that uses Redux for it's state management. I'm fairly new to Redux, and I'm working on building out the actions/reducers now and my question is: Do I need a separate action/reducer for each selection option or can I create a single action/reducer combo that works for all?

Comment: A single reducer that manages the state of your selections would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux have only one reducer.

[Configure store](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store) function for redux takes only one reducer as argument.

When the application grows complex reducers are splitted and then combined using [combined reducer](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) which generates a root reducer which is passed to the configure store function.

Also, [actions](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) are just javascript objects or Action Creators are just functions. They become actions when they are used with dispatch function of the store. You can use as many you want.
Your redux state change in the reducer will be defined by which action you pass.

Have a look at this basic [example](https://redux.js.org/basics/example) of redux.